# Can't encipher text in Ruby. It showes me the last letter of cipher-key in all my plaintext after iterating

Tags: ruby, ascii, each, cs50

Can't encipher text in Ruby. It showes me the last letter of cipher-key in all my plaintext after iterating.

**key is:** *VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI*

**plaintext is**: *Hello, CS-50!*

**expected**  **ciphered_text:** *Jrssb, HA-50!*

**I got ciphered_text:**                   *Iiiii, II-50!*

I don't know why I got a last letter of a key (I) in every char of ciphered_text....
Maybe I need a "break" after every succes "if". But it doesn't helped.

Here is my code:

```
# Design and implement a program, substitution, that encrypts messages using a substitution cipher.
plaintext_str = 'Hello, CS-50!'
key_str = 'VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI'

# Converting string into array:
plaintext = plaintext_str.split('')
key = key_str.split('')

# Check if letter is alphabetical
def alpha?(char)
  char.match?(/^[[:alpha:]]$/)
end

# Check if letter is in uppercase
def upper?(char)
  char.match?(/^[[:upper:]]$/)
end

# # Check if letter is in lowercase
def lower?(char)
  char.match?(/^[[:lower:]]$/)
end

# ASCII arrays value assigned to capital letters for alphabets
capital_letters = [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,
                   88, 89, 90]
# ASCII arrays value assigned to small letters for alphabets
small_letters = [97,
                 98,
                 99,
                 100,
                 101,
                 102,
                 103,
                 104,
                 105,
                 106,
                 107,
                 108,
                 109,
                 110,
                 111,
                 112,
                 113,
                 114,
                 115,
                 116,
                 117,
                 118,
                 119,
                 120,
                 121,
                 122]

# Define variable for ciphertext:
ciphertext = ''

# iterating each plaintext's char (i-th):
plaintext.each_index do |i|
  # iterating each key's char j-th on i-th char of plaintext:
  key.each_index do |j|
    # If char in plaintext is alphabetical:
    if alpha?(plaintext[i])
      # Check if letter is in uppercase
      if upper?(plaintext[i])
        capital_letters.each_index do |k|
          # Checking if plaintext's letter is equal to alphabet's letter in [j]
          if plaintext[i].ord == capital_letters[k]
            ciphertext[i] = key[j].upcase
            break
          end
        end
      # Check if letter is in lowercase
      elsif lower?(plaintext[i])
        small_letters.each_index do |l|
          if plaintext[i].ord == small_letters[l]
            ciphertext[i] = key[j].downcase
            break
          end
        end
      end
    # if non-alphabetical:
    else
      ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i]
    end
  end
end
puts "ciphertext: #{ciphertext}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a preface, the code you have here looks an awful lot like C. There are a lot of concepts that Ruby provides which can make problems like this into significantly shorter solutions. For now, we'll focus on what's wrong with your code as it is.

The main issue is you have three index variables, `i` from `plaintext`, `j` from `key`, and `k` from `capital_letters`. You check that if `plaintext[i] == capital_letters[k]`, then you place `key[j]` at the `i`th position. But, since `j` was never participating in the checks, you will simply pass this check for all indices in your key variable. So, you might as well have `ciphertext[i] = key.last.upcase`, and if you check `key`, the last entry is `I`, hence why your output is nothing but `I`'s.

Some suggestions for how you could simplify your code:

```rb
def encipher(plaintext, key)
  # Make a table that maps { plaintext character => target character }
  # With your input example, table = {"A" => "V", "B" => "C", "C" => "H", ... }
  table = key.chars
             .each_with_index
             .map { |sub, index| [Array("A".."Z")[index], sub] }
             .to_h
  
  plaintext.map { |char|
    # TODO: Using char and table, encipher exactly one character
  }.join
end
```